# creating an app in eclipse: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

im new here :)
my first question is, i got the error in eclipse wanting to create an app:

```
[2014-03-30 18:48:43 - brutto_netto_rechner] C:\Users\HP\!Studium!\Eclipse\brutto_netto_rechner\res\layout\formular_activity.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
```

And heres is the formular_activity.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FormularActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txt_anweisung" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/edt_betrag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/rg_art"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

 <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rb_art_netto"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/txt_netto"
     android:checked="true" />

 <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rb_art_brutto"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/txt_brutto" />
</RadioGroup>

<Spinner android:id="@+id/sp_umsatzsteuer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:entries="@array/ust_anzeige"
    android:entryValues="@array/ust_werte" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txt_berechnen"
    android:onClick="onClickBerechnen" />

</LinearLayout>
```

thats my first try creating an app, so if anybody could help, be specific.
Thank you!!

greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't define the tools namespace:

```
tools:context=".FormularActivity" >
```

This will refer to nothing

Add this line

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

just under

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Answer (score 0):

change like this::

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FormularActivity" >
```